# Retrofit @post parametres

Tags: android, json

I wish to send bankname and branchname to the URL

public interface MInterface {
    @GET("/api/getbank/{bank name}/{branch name}")

```
void getUser(@Path("bankname") String bankname,@Path("branchname") String branchname, Callback<Pojo> uscb);
```

}

RestAdapter radapter=new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(url).build();

```
    MInterface restInt=radapter.create(MInterface.class);

    String bankname="Yes bank";
    String branchname="ASSOCIATE COOP BANK UMARWADA";
    restInt.getUser(bankname ,branchname ,new Callback<Pojo>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Pojo model, Response response) {


            Data data =model.getData();
            String IFSC=data.getIFSC();
            Log.d("IFSCHandler","onBankSelected:::"+IFSC);


       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,IFSC, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            String err = error.getMessage();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting, specify it. And you cannot send data by using GET you have to use POST

Comment: am able to retrive list of branch by passing  bankname in this http://api.techm.co.in/api/listbranches/{bank name}   and now i want to pass bank name and branch name for this http://api.techm.co.in/api/getbank/{bank name}/{branch name}

Comment: api.techm.co.in/api/listbranches API is not working .please help me any one here

Answer (score 0):

use this if you have to use @GET

```
void getUser(@Query("bankname") String bankname,@Query("branchname") String branchname , Callback<Pojo> uscb);
```

if you have to use @POST then
and you have to use @FormUrlEncoded for this
void getUser(@Field("bankname") String bankname,@Field("branchname") String branchname , Callback uscb);

Answer (score 0):

***I hope this will help you.***

```
public interface Interface {

//This method is used for "POST"
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api.php")
Call<ServerResponse> post(
        @Field("bankname") String bankName,
        @Field("branchname") String branchName
);

//This method is used for "GET"
@GET("/api.php")
Call<ServerResponse> get(
        @Query("bankname") String bankName,
        @Query("branchname") String branchName
);
}


public void getBankDetails(String bankName, String branchName){
    //Here a logging interceptor is created
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    //The logging interceptor will be added to the http client
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

    //The Retrofit builder will have the client attached, in order to get connection logs
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(SERVER_URL)
            .build();

    Interface service = retrofit.create(Interface.class);

    Call<ServerResponse> call = service.get(bankName,branchName);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ServerEvent(response.body()));
            Log.e(TAG,"Success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            // handle execution failures like no internet connectivity
            BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ErrorEvent(-2,t.getMessage()));
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks